# Type Error : calling nested functions in backbone.js views / models

Tags: backbone.js

Basically custom nested functions not working in either BackBone views & models, getting an error "TypeError:not a function" or "Undefined". Below is the sample code snippet using backbone.js

Scenario_1:

```
sampleX : function() {
    this.sampleZ();

    sampleY(function() {
        this.sampleZ();
    });
}
```

When the line this.sampleZ() was invoked inside sampleY() function, getting an error like "TypeError : this.sampleZ() is not a function."

Scenario_2:

```
sampleX : function() {
    this.sampleY();
},
sampleY : fucntion (){
        this.sampleZ();     
},
sampleZ : fucntion(){
        ...
}
```

When I tried calling sampleY() inside sampleX() its invoking, but sampleZ() is not calling which is trying to invoke inside sampleY() function.

Any help would be appreciated on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have problem with **context** in

```
sampleY(function() {
    this.sampleZ();
});
```

use bind function... otherwise **'this'** is not what you are expecting

```
    this.sampleY1(_.bind(function() {             
        this.sampleZ1();
    }, this));
```

This works for me:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        someKey: 'test123'
    },  

    sampleZ1: function(){
        console.log('Z1');
    },
    sampleX1 : function() {
        console.log('X1');
        this.sampleZ1();        

        this.sampleY1(_.bind(function() {             
            this.sampleZ1();
        }, this));
    },
    sampleY1: function(callback) {
        console.log('Y1');
        callback();
    },    

    sampleX2: function() {
        console.log('X2');
        this.sampleY2();
    },
    sampleY2: function () {
        console.log('Y2');
        this.sampleZ2();     
    },
    sampleZ2: function(){
        console.log('Z2');
    }        

});

var testMdl = new Model();
testMdl.sampleX1();
console.log('----');
testMdl.sampleX2();
```

Comment: this.sampleY1(_.bind(function() {             
        this.sampleZ1();
    }, this));                                                                                                                                i tried as per you suggestion, but getting the same problem.